# GoogleDrive App in Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm learning about googleDrive to writing a app which can access GoogleDrive. I search code on google a lot of time but i don't have anything. Who can give me a source code for this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the links given below, these contains sample demo codes as well,

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/

https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos

Thanks.